# How to work correctly with a 3-way pivot table without losing performance?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship

My tables:
Pivot table

```
Schema::create('product_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('property_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('property_value_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Product table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('article')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug', 100)->unique();
            $table->foreignId('group_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('brand_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('catalog_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Property table

```
Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->integer('order')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

PropertyValue table

```
Schema::create('property_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->foreignId('property_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('value');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

All Eloquent relationships in the models are configured according to Laravel documentation.

Product

```
    public function properties() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_id')
            ->with('values')
            ->withPivot('property_value_id');
    }

    public function values() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class,'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_value_id');
    }
```

Property

```
    public function products() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property', 'property_id', 'product_id')->with('values');
    }

    public function values() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PropertyValue::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id');
    }
```

PropertyValue

```
    public function properties() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Property::class, 'product_property','property_id','property_value_id');
    }

    public function products() :BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_property','property_value_id','product_id');
    }
```

How do I request all the properties+values of the specified products and output as:

```
Array
(
    ['PROPERTY NAME 1'] => Array
        (
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 1'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 1 VALUE'
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 2'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 2 VALUE'
        )

    ['PROPERTY NAME 2'] => Array
        (
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 1'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 1 VALUE'
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 2'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 2 VALUE'
        )

    ['PROPERTY NAME 3'] => Array
        (
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 1'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 1 VALUE'
            ['PROPERTY_VALUE ID 2'] => 'PROPERTY_VALUE 2 VALUE'
        )

)
```

I tried it like this:

```
$productsId = 'any_products_id'

Property::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($productsId) {
            $query->whereIn('product_id', $productsId);
        })->whereHas('values', function ($query) use ($productsId) {
            $query->whereIn('product_id', $productsId);
        })->orderBy('order')->get();
```

But this creates the problem of a huge number of loaded models.
How do I generate such an array without losing performance?